# Websockets for Tomcat 7 AND 8

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

The way to implement WebSockets in Tomcat changed between version 7 and version 8.

Tomcat 7:

```
public class ChatWebSocketServlet extends WebSocketServlet { ... }
```

Tomcat 8:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/chat")
public class ChatAnnotation { ... }
```

What I want to know is if it's possible to build both versions into a single application. I already tried

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/chat")
public class ChatServlet extends WebSocketServlet { ... }
```

but it never compiles against *both* websocket-api.jar and catalina.jar. I guess it's possible to check if a class is defined and use one or the other at runtime, but I'm not sure how to implement that exactly, or even whether it's a good idea.

I could package the websocket-api.jar into the final product, but would that cause problems deploying it to Tomcat 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Tomcat 7](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html) *and* [Tomcat 8](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html) documentation

> ## Application development
>
> Tomcat implements the Java WebSocket 1.1 API defined by JSR-356.

From Tomcat 7 documentation:

> ## Deprecated proprietary API
>
> Prior to the development of JRS-356, Tomcat provided a proprietary WebSocket API. This API has been deprecated in Tomcat 7 and will be
>   removed in Tomcat 8. There is unlikely to be any further development
>   of this proprietary API apart from bug fixes.
>
> For information on this API, please see the Javadoc for the org.apache.catalina.websocket package. The Javadoc pages are not
>   included with Tomcat binary distributions. To view them locally you
>   would have to download and install "Full documentation" distribution,
>   or build it from sources. You can also read this on the Apache Tomcat
>   web site. Start with the `WebSocketServlet` class.

I doubt that you can use both implementations at the same time, but according to the documentation you shouldn't have a problem with JSR-356 specific implementations running on both versions. Just stay away from the proprietary implementation.

As the first version of Tomcat 7 was released in 2010/2011, but JSR-356 was first released in 2013, there are ancient versions that don't have the standard websocket implementation, and I'll leave to you to find out in which version the JSR-356 implementation was included first. However, due to bugfixes, including security relevant ones, you should have an easy time to only support the latest version of Tomcat 7. Don't worry about those that didn't update their server software for several years.

Comment: This was right. Critically, the demo Tomcat 7 system I was working with was 7.0.39, which made me conclude that you couldn't use annotations in Tomcat 7. But you can, and I agree it's not too much to ask for the latest revision of a version.